# How to do Buefy autocomplete on multiple fields

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, buefy

I'm developing autocomplete using buefy autocomplete. It works fine for single field from object - `{BrandID: 1004487, BrandName: "test"}` Currently filtering data on `BrandName`

Below is code -

```
<b-autocomplete class="form-control"
  v-model.trim="newMapping.brandname"
  placeholder="Type brand name..."
  :data="filteredBrandData"
  field="BrandName"
  size="is-small"
  :open-on-focus="true"
  @select="option => newMapping.brandid = option.BrandID"
  @typing="clearBrand()">
  <template slot-scope="props">
   <div class="media">
     <div class="media-content">
       {{props.option.BrandName}}
       <br>
       <small>
         BrandId : {{props.option.BrandID}}
       </small>
     </div>
    </div>
   </template>
</b-autocomplete>
```

Vuejs function -

```
filteredBrandData () {
  return this.brandList.filter((text) => {
    return text.BrandName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.newMapping.brandname.toLowerCase()) >= 0
  })
}
```

I want to filter / autocomplete data on `BrandID` as well, How do I fix this? please suggest.

Buefy autocomplete - https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on b-autocomplete: `@select="option => mySelectFunction(option)"`

On script:

```
private mySelectFunction(option: {code: string; description: string}){
    this.myModel.code = option.code
    this.myModel.description = option.description
}
```